# ReactJS + MaterialUI: How to recognize that <TableRow/>'s checkbox been clicked on?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Using ReactJS + MaterialUI's '' (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table), I have created a table with two rows, each with a checkbox. Once a checkbox has been clicked on, how can I get a method to recognize the event of the row and along with the information for that particular row?

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Table, TableBody, TableHeader, TableHeaderColumn, TableRow, TableRowColumn} from 'material-ui/Table';

class TableExample extends Component {
  <Table>
    <TableHeader>
      <TableRow>
        <TableHeaderColumn>Row Count</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn>Color</TableHeaderColumn>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHeader>
    <TableBody>
      <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>John Smith</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>White</TableRowColumn>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn>2</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Randal White</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Green</TableRowColumn>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn>3</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Stephanie Sanders</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>Black</TableRowColumn>
      </TableRow>
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
);

export default TableExample
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an event prop `onRowSelection` on `Table` component for that. Please check the docu you have linked.

Comment: Sorry I tried it but didn't work. Could you show an example so I can accept the answer and upvote it? Also how would the row recognize the information for that particular row (e.g. 1, John Smith, white)?

Comment: Just checking to see if you've seen my last comment. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Just as user **mschayna** mentioned, You can use `onRowSelection` event prop on `Table`

Example

```
<Table
  onRowSelection={ this.handleRowSelection }
>
...
</Table>
```

And in your **handleRowSelection** function, You will receive an array containing all the rows that a user has selected

```
handleRowSelection( selectedRows ) {
  // selectedRows contains all the rows that have been selected by the user.
  // If all rows have been selected then selectedRows will be a string and its value will be 'all'

  if ( selectedRows === "all" ) {
    // all the rows in the table has been selected by the user
    // add your logic here.

  } else {
    // selectedRows is an array
    // iterate over it.
    selectedRows.map( (row) => {
      // here you can access specific rows details.
      console.log('row', row);
      // your logic here.
    });

  }

}
```

However, You can also do it like this

```
<Table>
  <TableHeader>
    ...
  </TableHeader>
  <TableBody>
    <TableRow onClick={ () => { handleRowClick(1, 'John Smith', 'White') } }>
      <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>John Smith</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>White</TableRowColumn>
    </TableRow>
    ...
```

And in the **handleRowClick** function, you can add the logic

```
handleRowClick( id, name, color ) {
  // this will be called when a user clicks on the row.
  console.log(`Users id is ${id} and name is ${name} and color is ${color}`);
}
```

> Once a checkbox has been clicked on, how can I get a method to recognize the event of the row and along with the information for that particular row?

You can add this code on the checkbox input, But do remember you have to check it if its checked or not.

`onChange={ (event) => { handleRowClick(1, 'John Smith', 'White', event) } }`

Note the new **event** param being passed to the function., You can now access the event data and see if a checkbox is checked or not.

Play around with this code, make the changes wherever necessary and use the method you're most comfortable with.